# Spotify raw output sounds garbled when interpreted as PCM

Tags: spotify, pcm

The output from `music_delivery` callback, when interpreted as a little endian 16bit signed integer PCM, with the same sample rate (44100Hz) and number of channels (2) as the audio samples in the `sp_audioformat` object, sounds recognisable, but very garbled, and in addition there are random bursts of noise throughout.

Does Spotify use a PCM format that isn't the same as standard, interleaved, PCM?

Comment: Just from the way it sounds and the way the waveform looks, I think Spotify PCM is not interleaved, half the samples destined for one channel, half for the other. Will attempt to interleave and see what it sounds like.

Answer (score 2):

I had misunderstood what `frames` meant in the context of the documentation for the `music_delivery` callback.

To find out how many samples there are available in the delivery callback, you have to multiply the number of frames by the number of channels.

It sounds great now!